# Display PHP multidimenisional array in html table

Tags: php, arrays

i have this array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => TotalVisits
            [1] => 360
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => TotalUnique
            [1] => 246
        )

)
```

I want diplay it like this :

```
TotalVisits | TotalUnique | 
---------------------------
360         | 246         |
```

Any way i could do that ? Thanks!
I tried this :

```
$fields = array(

        0 => $general[0][0] ,
        1 => $general[1][0] ,
    ) ; 
    echo '<div id="collapse_awstats_extract_sider" class="accordion-body collapse in">';
        echo '<div class="accordion-inner">';
            print_table(array(0 => $general[0],1 => $general[1]), $fields); 
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
```

but it displays like this

```
TotalVisits     TotalUnique
TotalVisits     360
TotalUnique     246
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use foreach loop:

```
$array = array(array('TotalVisits', 360), array('TotalUnique', 246));
$headers = array($array[0][0], $array[1][0]);
$values = array($array[0][1], $array[1][1]);

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
foreach($headers as $name) {
   echo '<th>' . $name . '</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';
foreach($values as $element) {
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>' . $element . '</td>';
   echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```